# get all embeds_many relationship keys from model definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

How can I get all the keys for embeds_many relationships defined on a model definition? When I do `Model.attribute_names`, it only gives me keys for the fields defined in the document schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model name is `User`, you can get all the embedded_many relations as follows:

```
embeds_many_relations = User.relations.select { |k, v| v.relation == Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::Many }
```

This returns a hash of embeds_many relations.

To get the keys:

```
embeds_many_relations.map { |k, _| k }
```

And if you store your associations using an alias i.e. `embeds_many :phones, store_as: :phs`, then you can get the database keys by calling:

```
embeds_many_relations.map { |_, v| v.key }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much.